# Identifying a broken Rotary Encoder on guitar foot pedal

Tags: identification, guitar-pedal

I have a guitar foot pedal, "EHX Stereo Memory Man with Hazarai", with a rotary encoder that broke off. Here is a picture of the knob in question:

[image]

Also, here is a picture of the circuit board, where the board is labelled 'ENC1' :

[image]

I have removed the rotary encoder but the shaft is snapped and deformed preventing me from testing its ability to be a push button. There are no part numbers on the part at all, and I emailed the manufacturer asking for the part number but was told only to send it in. There are 3 pins on one side of it and two on the other. If you like I'll upload some pics of just the encoder.

**Update: I so here is a photo of the underside with a strange H8 marking. I think I found a suitable replacement part to try out show in pic 4:**

[image]
[image]

That last one is a product i found at a company called Seeed and is titled a 'Rotary Encoder with Switch' for $3.70

Comment: The shape of the pins is quite unlike any ordinary manufacturer (round bend, no taper or gusset). Maybe there is some marking on underside of the plastic base, beneath the metal clamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same part. In particular, the side with the two pins indicate that there is a switch in the encoder. The only difference might be the number of clicks per revolution ( clicks per turn). But then it will only change the speed of incrementation/decrementation.